# Overriding parse_start_url() in Scrapy and limiting crawl depth to 1

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using Scrapy to crawl a site and have overridden `parse_start_url()` in order to scrape the start URLs.

However, this means that when I set the `DEPTH_LIMIT` setting to 1, Scrapy crawls at depth 2 (because I guess it makes sense for the start urls not to count towards the depth, if they're usually parsed). This is ok when crawling at any depth other than 1, because I can just reduce the `DEPTH_LIMIT` by 1 to account for this. However, this won't work when crawling at depth 1 because a `DEPTH_LIMIT` of 0 is treated as unlimited depth.

Can anyone think of a way to parse start URLs and have a depth limit of 1?

Or should I write my own `DepthMiddleware`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you yield requests from [`parse_start_url()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) method, set the `meta['depth']`:

```
yield Request(url, meta={'depth': 1})
```

This should do the trick since later, when the response would arrive, in the [`DepthMiddleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) it would be incremented by 1:

```
def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    def _filter(request):
        if isinstance(request, Request):
            depth = response.meta['depth'] + 1
            ...
```